# Issues installing tools for Windows 10 Universal apps after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I installed Visual Studio 2015 on my machine before I upgraded to Windows 10 a few days ago. I'm having a really hard time installing W10 universal apps. At first, the option for universal apps wasn't listed under project templates. After a few restarts and back and forth, the option was there, the installation of the tools took several hours (I'm on an SSD so installations usually happens within a few minutes). Once it got installed, I either got an error message about loading assemblies, or that the project is not compatible with my version of Visual Studio (I'm running Visual Studio 2015 enterprise).

I have tried repairing and uninstalling then reinstalling/repairing VS, where the result is usually that the situation gets somewhat worse. Now, only test projects are listed under the Windows UAP section (Not Universal). I have also tried both uninstalling and reinstalling the Windows 10 SDK separately with Visual Studio without any effect. Is there a way to perform a complete clean uninstall of Visual Studio 2015 without performing a reinstall of my OS or is there some cache that I should clear?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just tried installing it, and the templates don't appear for me either.

Comment: @James Sorry but I was unfortunately unable to find a solution to this problem. I ended up resetting my PC in order to get a clean Windows build to set everything up freshly.

Comment: Oh no! Thanks anyway, Martin. Sorry to hear it was a pain

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall the windows 10 two sdks using the VS installer then open VS again. The universal template showing up. Then install the SDK again and it worked. Hope this will help.